# Parsing Soap Envelope to Dataset in C#

Tags: c#, soap

This is my soap response format  [link](http://pastebin.com/QzrDz6sN/)
I'm trying to store the soap response into a data set and retrieve the results

```
 Stream rd= new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
 soapresults rd.ReadToEnd();
 XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
 XmlNodeReader xmlRead= new XmlNodeReader(doc);
 ds.ReadXml(xmlRead);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string data1 = dt.Rows[0]["DATA1"].ToString();
    }
}
```

So far I haven't been able.

Here is the XML:

```
<ns3:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns2="http://www.fiorano.com/fesb/activity/DBQueryOnInput1/Out" 
xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns3:Body>
  <ns2:Result>
     <ns2:rows>
        <row resultcount="1" xmlns="http://www.fiorano.com/fesb/activity/DBQueryOnInput1/Out">
           <DATA1>THANK YOU</DATA1>
           <DATA2>FOR</DATA2>
           <DATA3>YOUR</DATA3>
           <DATA4>ASSISTANCE</DATA4>
          </row>
     </ns2:rows>
     <ns2:updatecount>1</ns2:updatecount>
  </ns2:Result>
</ns3:Body>
</ns3:Envelope>
```

Comment: So what happens when you try that code? (It looks like it wouldn't compile, to start with...)

Comment: Is your dataset filled at the line ? 
**ds.ReadXml(xmlRead);**

Comment: And why don't you just use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Rohit The dataset is filled...I get Exception Column `DATA1 does not belong to table Body`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Noted.

Comment: @Angwenyi, Ok. Do you have column named "DATA1" in your first Table ? or you can also apply check like- **dt.Columns["DATA1"] != null**

Comment: @Rohit from the xml I noted i reads `<ns3:Body>` as the table how can I go to the `<DATA1>' nodes and read its values.

Comment: @Angwenyi, Can you post the xml  (if xml is too big, only the part of the column) ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the xml response

Comment: @Angwenyi, and What are columns names? in your first table ? you can see the columns name in debug mode by putting a breakpoint on line- **if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)** and check the columns name in **dt **.

Comment: The column name seeing on debug mode is `{Body}`

Comment: @Angwenyi, This is what your SOAP envelope returning the column name for the table. I dont' have much experience in SOAP, but I am sure, that would be your xml schema to decide the table structure. Anyway, you can get the column value with **string data1 = dt.Rows[0]["Body"].ToString();**

Comment: My main challenge here is to transverse to to the `<DATA>' nodes

Comment: In that case, you can use LINQ to XML. and you can read the xml as you want. . . ..

Comment: @Rohit I think i will have to use go that way

Comment: using LINQ to xml to play with XML is a much better idea. You can do whatever you want to do with the xmls and values inside that .  . . ..